# How to set struts2jquery Grid column names from JSON result of action

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I have a [Struts 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) action returning a JSON result.

```
{"columns":["coupon","CM","CM+1","CM+2","CM+3"],"couponList":[{"coupon":3.0,"CM":"88.2323","CM+1":"89.45","CM+2":"132.3128125","CM+3":"32.82"},{"coupon":3.5,"CM":"25","CM+1":"3125","CM+2":"333","CM+3":"5"}],"Caption":"30 Yr Fixed"}
```

I am able to populate the grid with the data. How do I populate the column names and caption using the "columns", "Caption" property returned in the JSON result?

I am using the S2Jquery tag library. @JSP

```
    <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jqgrid_gcpm.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/gcp.css">
<sj:head />

<s:url id="actionurl" action="testAction">
    <s:set var="caption" value="Caption" />
</s:url>

<sjg:grid id="gridtable" caption="%{caption}" dataType="json"
    href="%{actionurl}" pager="false" gridModel="couponList"
    rowNum="-1" rownumbers="false" altRows="true" autowidth="true"
    resizable="true" shrinkToFit="true">
    <sjg:gridColumn name="coupon" index="coupon" title="Coupon"
        sortable="false" width="30" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="CM" title="CM" sortable="false"
        formatter="htmlFormatter" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="CM+1" title="CM+1"
        sortable="false" formatter="htmlFormatter" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="CM+2" title="CM+2"
        sortable="false" formatter="htmlFormatter" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="CM+3" title="CM+3"
        sortable="false" formatter="htmlFormatter" />
</sjg:grid>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function htmlFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
        if (cellValue == null) {
            return '';
        }
        else {
            return cellValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the S2 jquery tag library or writing javascript? If the the former post the JSP, if the later remove any mention of S2 from the question and show the script.

Comment: I am using S2Jquery tag library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and my solution was:

```
var myfirstrow = {description:"1"};
$("#cashReceiptLines").jqGrid('addRowData',"1", myfirstrow);
```

This is my grid

```
<sjg:grid
id="cashReceiptLines"
caption="Cash receipt lines"
gridModel="cashReceiptLines"
rowNum="15"
width="860"
dataType= "local"
rownumbers="true">
<sjg:gridColumn name="description" index="description" title="Description"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

Alex Vicente Chacón Jiménez
alex.chacon@software-colombia.com

Comment: Thanks Alex Vicente. I started to use the jqGrid itself and not the s2j grid. For Now populating the label for column directly in the action. Working code in this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111653/problem-showing-jqgrid-with-dynamic-column-binding)     I will try the way you did and let you know. Thanks again.