# How to add custom Formatter for jqgrid with dynamic column binding

Tags: jqgrid

This is almost continuation of a previous question. [Problem showing jqgrid with dynamic column binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111653/problem-showing-jqgrid-with-dynamic-column-binding)

I am trying to put a Custom Formatter for the columns like below. But nothing happens. Please help.

JSP:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax( {
    type : "GET",
    url : "interFinalTbaAction",
    data : "",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(result) {
        var colD = result.couponStripList, colM = result.colModelList;
        jQuery("#InterFinalTBAGrid").jqGrid( {
            data : colD.rootVar,
            datatype : 'local',
            gridview : true,
            colModel : colM,
            loadComplete : function(data) {
            },
            loadError : function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert('grid loading error');
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(x, e) {
        alert(x.readyState + " " + x.status + " " + e.msg);
    }
});
  });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table id="InterFinalTBAGrid">
<tr>
    <td />
</tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The JSON result from action:

```
 {
"colModelList": [
    {
        "formatter": "CouponFormatter",
        "index": 0,
        "jsonmap": null,
        "key": false,
        "label": "Coupon",
        "name": "coupon",
        "resizable": true,
        "search": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "title": true,
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "formatter": "InterFinalPriceFormatter",
        "index": 1,
        "jsonmap": null,
        "key": false,
        "label": "03-10-11",
        "name": "prceCM",
        "resizable": true,
        "search": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "title": true,
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "formatter": "InterFinalPriceFormatter",
        "index": 2,
        "jsonmap": null,
        "key": false,
        "label": "04-13-11",
        "name": "prceCMPlusOne",
        "resizable": true,
        "search": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "title": true,
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "formatter": "InterFinalPriceFormatter",
        "index": 3,
        "jsonmap": null,
        "key": false,
        "label": "05-12-11",
        "name": "prceCMPlusTwo",
        "resizable": true,
        "search": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "title": true,
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "formatter": "InterFinalPriceFormatter",
        "index": 4,
        "jsonmap": null,
        "key": false,
        "label": "06-13-11",
        "name": "prceCMPlusThree",
        "resizable": true,
        "search": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "title": true,
        "width": 150
      }
   ],
   "couponStripList": {
    "rootVar": [
        {
            "coupon": 5.0,
            "prceCM": "103.734375,103.734375",
            "prceCMPlusOne": "103.359375,99.03",
            "prceCMPlusThree": "102.671875,102.671875",
            "prceCMPlusTwo": "103.015625,103.015625"
        },
        {
            "coupon": 5.5,
            "prceCM": "105.984375,105.984375",
            "prceCMPlusOne": "105.671875,99.2",
            "prceCMPlusThree": "105.046875,105.046875",
            "prceCMPlusTwo": "105.359375,105.359375"
        }

    ]
   },
   "deliveredDataTimestamp": "03-02-11 11:52:57",
   "requestedTimestamp": null
   }
```

The Javascript functions for formatters:

```
  function CouponFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
return cellValue + "Testing coupon formatter";
   }

function InterFinalPriceFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
return cellValue + "Testing price formatter";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use

```
"formatter": "InterFinalPriceFormatter"
```

you don't set the value of "formatter" property to the **function**.

One way to fix the problem is to loop through `result.colModelList` and verify that one use "formatter" property with some string value for which you has implementation as the function in the JavaScript. Then you can overwrite the property with the value of the corresponding formatter function.

Another way will be use inline functions in the formatter:

```js
"formatter": "function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) { return cellValue + \"Testing price formatter\"; }"
```

In the way you will be not has clear separation of the code and the grid parameters, but you receive some encapsulation of the formatter inside the grid.

**UPDATED**: I hope that the next code fragment (untested) could make clear what I mean under the first implementation way

```js
var functionsMapping = {
    // here we define the implementations of the custom formatter which we use
    "CouponFormatter": function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
        return cellValue + "Testing coupon formatter";
    },
    "InterFinalPriceFormatter": function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
        return cellValue + "Testing price formatter";
    }
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "interFinalTbaAction.action",
    data: "",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        var i, cm, colD = result.couponStripList,
            colN = result.columnNames,
            colM = result.colModelList;
        for (i=0;i<colM.length,i++) {
            cm = colM[i];
            if (cm.hasOwnProperty("formatter") &&
                functionsMapping.hasOwnProperty(cm.formatter)) {
                // fix colM[i].formatter from string to the function
                cm.formatter = functionsMapping[cm.formatter];
            }
        }
        jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid({/* all parameters from your code */});
    },         
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error Occured!" + " | " + jqXHR.responseText + " | " +
              textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**UPDATED 2:** It would be better to **register** the custom formatters and unformatters as *standard formatters* like it's described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625715/315935) or in [answer one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877272/315935). After that one can really use the syntax like `"formatter": "InterFinalPriceFormatter"` and the custom defined functions `$.fn.fmatter.InterFinalPriceFormatter` and `$.fn.fmatter.InterFinalPriceFormatter.unformat` will be automatically called by jqGrid.

Comment: I understood the inline function part but didnt get the first part. When I loop through the `result.colModelList` how do I replace with the formatter fucntion? Can you put some pseudo code example please?

Comment: Is it something like, var InterFinalPriceFormatter = " function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) { return cellValue + \"Testing price formatter\"; }"

Comment: @silpa: I updates my answer. The `var InterFinalPriceFormatter = " function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) { return cellValue + \"Testing price formatter\"; }";` defines the variable `InterFinalPriceFormatter` having `typeof(InterFinalPriceFormatter) === "string"` and `var InterFinalPriceFormatter = function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) { return cellValue + \"Testing price formatter\"; };` defines the function and `typeof(InterFinalPriceFormatter) === function"`"

Comment: Thank You. Works perfectly. I was also looking into this link[sending javascript functions over json](http://solutoire.com/2008/06/12/sending-javascript-functions-over-json/) before you updated the answer.

Comment: @volocuga: You are welcome! It's relatively old answer. Now I would you recommend better to extend `$.fn.fmatter` object to defined formatters which you could directly use as *string*: `formatter: "InterFinalPriceFormatter"`. You can find corresponding code examples [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) and in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935). It's important that it allows to use formatter as string `formatter: "dynamicLink"` instead of function `formatter: dynamicLinkFunction`.

Comment: @Oleg i am use number formatter so i want to change decimalPlaces dynamically is it poosible?

Comment: @AshuMehta: You can change *any* property of `colModel` inclusive `formatoptions`. You can use `setColProp` method which simplify changes. If you load the information from the server then you can change `formatoptions` inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. In the case the filling of jqGrid will uses the changed `colModel` values.

Comment: I am sorry: how do I get the column name, or ID ? rowObject.columnid won't work !

Comment: @JessStone: One can't answer on your question without to know details. Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce` (if `datatype: "json"`)? Which format have **input data** of jqGrid (which `jsonReader` you use)? How `colModel` is defined? and so on. It's better you ask *new question* where you post all the details.

Comment: @Oleg [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634037/jqsuite-php-get-column-name-or-id)