# JSON encoded formatter function name

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, json

I'm using jqgrid for which I create column definitions on server as dynamic objects and serialize them using Json.Encode:

```
html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(ColumnDefinition);
```

I have problem with applying custom formatter, as my serialized column definition is:

```
{"name":"Icon","index":"Icon","hidden":false,"formatter":"iconFormatter","unformat":{}}
```

Problem is in quotes which are added to all keys and values to respect JSON specification, and those around *iconFormatter* are problem in my case as I want that to be my function.
Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have the same or close problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171617/how-to-add-custom-formatter-for-jqgrid-with-dynamic-column-binding/5175127#5175127). You will have to replace the string values of the `formatter` properties to **the function reference**. Pragmatic way is to search for the strings like `"iconFormatter"` (search for all custom formatters which you use) and replace there to the corresponding function refernce.

**UPDATED**: If you would be use `template` property inside of column definition (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856)) you would be solve the problem in another way. Additionally you code will be shorter, more clear and better readable.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that search&replace on server, before Html.Raw, but I don't like that, as it solves only formatter problem, and there will be more functions. I will try now with functionsMapping and foreach through column models replacing that after jqgrid construction.

Comment: @Oleg thanks, I have updated this post with solution based on first link you posted. Template is not what I need in this case, but it is very useful feature as I can declare part of definition in view. Thanks

Comment: @obrad: It seems to me that the usage of column templates whould be the better way. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856) for detailes. See one more demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) which use templates. Ohh! Now it seems to me that you do would has the same problems.

Comment: @Oleg I'm aware (now :)) that it is also possible to do this with template by declaring formatter in template, but I did not do that because I need to add that property into my ColumnModel on server side, and update column definition, which will what I will do and put this into template also if anything else arrives that should be done with this column :)

Comment: Hm, it seems changing formatter after grid construction does not work (jqgrid does not apply new function). It seems that I have to use first solution (string replace) in combination with template, so only replacement will be that for template name.

Comment: @obrad: I think that any way is possible. If you change the formatter on a column you will have to reload the grid with `$("#gridid").trigger("reloadGrid")`.

Comment: @obrad: I agree that no the ways are perfect, but one can quickly make any from the ways working.