# Offval attribute custom checkbox formatter jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am writing a custom checkbox formatter and I have trouble understanding where the `offval` attribute is used for and what it value should be.

Especially when the value of the editoptions are set. For example `editoptions: { value:"Yes:No" }`

I can see that the default checkbox formatter always sets the `offval` to `no`. This [api documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) says it can also be set to `off`. In the code I also see that the value can be set to the second value of the editoptions. In case of the example to `No` but this can be any provided value.

So how do I implement the offval attribute for my checkbox formatter? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need to set any `offval` attribute inside of your custom checkbox formatter. jqGrid set the attribute itself if one uses `edittype: "checkbox"` (see [the part of code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L307-L330)). So it seems to me that **you don't need to set `offval`** neither in your [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) nor in [custom editing control](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) if you create it too.

By the way in the time when I posted the code of [formatter: "clickableCheckbox"](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.clickableCheckbox.js) I had the same question as you. I didn't understood the mean of `offval` and I just included `offval="no"` in the code. :-). I don't think that it has any sense, but to be sure one have to test all of cause.

If you write your custom formatter which you use multiple times I would recommend you to use

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        yourFormatterName: function (cellValue, options) {
            ....
        }
    });
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter.yourFormatterName, {
        unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
            ...
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

as prototype of the formatter. In the way you will register new formatter "yourFormatterName" which you can use exactly like any other [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types): you need just use `formatter: "yourFormatterName"` instead of `formatter: "checkbox"` in the column definition of the corresponding column. I find this way very practical.

Comment: I already use the format you provided :-). Will post mine formatter when it's finished, first need to clarify the offval attribute. I see it's also being used here https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.formedit.js#L398-L404

Comment: @MartijnB: You referenced the code of from **form editing**. The controls in the form was created by `createEl` function which I referenced in my answer. So if one use `edittype: "checkbox"` the `offval` will be set based on the value which return your `unformat` function. So I continue to think that no `offval` attribute are required or be used in the **formatter**.

Comment: I beginning to believe you are right. But then I don't understand why the default checkbox formatter includes the offval.

Comment: @MartijnB: I think that every program can be improved. :-) jqGrid will be permanently improved too.

Comment: I let the question open for now until next week otherwise I mark this as answered by you - my current progress so far - https://gist.github.com/4673081