# jqGrid - disable individual inline checkbox?

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid where one column has

> ... formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false }

I would like to toggle the **disabled** value based on other columns for the same row. The result would be a grid with some enabled and some disabled checkboxes.

Is this possible?

I tried putting a function in the **formatoptions** value - `formatoptions: { disabled: somefunction()}` but it only got called once at table load and didn't seem to accept any parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) or register your custom formatter like it's described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625715/315935) or in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640665/315935) and call the original custom formatter *inside of* it:

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        yourFormatterName: function (cellValue, options,
                rowObject, action) {

            // call formatter: "checkbox"
            return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "checkbox",
                cellValue, options, rowObject, action);
        }
    });
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter.yourFormatterName, {
        unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
            var cbv = (options.colModel.editoptions != null &&
                        typeof options.colModel.editoptions.value === "string") ?
                            options.colModel.editoptions.value.split(":") :
                            ["Yes","No"];
            ret = $("input", elem).is(":checked") ? cbv[0] : cbv[1];
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

In the way you can change any property of `options.colModel` **before** calling the original formatter:

```js
yourFormatterName: function (cellValue, options, rowObject, action) {
    var myValue = true, // or false value DYNAMICALLY
        newOptions = $.extend(true, {
                colModel: { formatoptions: { disabled: myValue } }
            },
            options);
    return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "checkbox", cellValue, newOptions, rowObject,
        action);
}
```

where

Comment: Hello @Oleg I just tried doing this making minor changes. This doesn't seem to work anymore. Maybe something changed in versions of free-jqGrid. Can you please have a look when you have a second? Thanks.

Comment: @DipenShah: It's better that you share the code which you tried... In any way I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/wugfty1o/ for you where I uses exact code which I included in the answer and the formatter `formatter: "yourFormatterName"` works.

Comment: Many thanks @Oleg. I had a simple misunderstanding and made a simple typo in my code which I fixed by looking at your demo. You are great help. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered this issue before. Instead of implementing a custom function in `formatoptions`, I loop each row of the grid in the `loadComplete` event and enable/disable the checkbox based on the value of another column. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/cowr1wyy/2/) out.

The all checkboxes in third column are based on the value of second `Name` column.