# how to set custom title for jqgrid cell when grid data binding is dynamic

Tags: javascript, dynamic, data-binding, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with dynamic data binding, and required to set a custom title for each cell. I applied the method described in the solution for 
[JQGrid with dynamic column: cellattr does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360466/jqgrid-with-dynamic-column-cellattr-does-not-work)

but it does not work. My code is as follows.

The action method that sets the colModel:

```
var result = new { 
    Json = new { 
        colNames = new[] { "T1", "T2" }, 
        colModels = new[] { 
            new { index = "T1", label = "T1", name = "T1", 
                width = 100, cellattr = "customTitle", 
                editable = true, strtooltip = "A0" }, 
            new { index = "T2", label = "T2", name = "T2", 
                width = 100, cellattr = "customTitle", 
                editable = true, strtooltip = "A1" 
            } 
        }, 
        data = ......................

$.ajax({
    url: '/Client/PatientListing/GetTestData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        var colModels = result.Json.colModels;
        var colNames = result.Json.colNames;
        var data = result.Json.data.options;
        jQuery.each(colModels, function (index, value) {
            debugger;
            cm = value;
            if (cm.hasOwnProperty("cellattr") &&
                functionsMapping.hasOwnProperty(cm.cellattr)) {
                cm.cellattr = functionsMapping[cm.cellattr];
            }
        });

        var functionsMapping = {
            "customTitle": function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
                return 'title="' + rawObject.T1 + ' (' + rawObject.T2 + ')"';
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to returns JSON data from the server, which contains `cellattr`. It's possible if you use more recent version of jqGrid. You can defined custom string name, which you can use as values of `cellattr` callbacks in the following way.

```
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.jgrid.cellattr = $.jgrid.cellattr || {};
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.cellattr, {
    customTitle: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
        return 'title="' + rawObject.T1 + ' (' + rawObject.T2 + ')"';
    },
    customTitle2: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
        return 'title="' + rawObject.T1 + ' [' + rawObject.T2 + ']"';
    }
});
```

Now you can use `cellattr: "customTitle"` and `cellattr: "customTitle2"` in the column definition.

By the way, free jqGrid support more parameters of `cellattr`. It has additional parameters `cm` and `rdata`. The parameter `cm` is the item of `colModel` which will be processed currently and the `rdata` is close to `rawObject`, but it's has always the same format with named properties. The problem is that `rawObject` used in `cellattr`, `rowattr` and custom formatters have exactly *the same* format like the input data. If you process XML input data, then the `rawObject` is an XML node. If you process JSON input with the data in the array form ["1",  "2007-10-01", "test", "note", "200.00", "10.00", "true", "TN", "210.00"] instead of `{id: "1",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"` and you use `loadonce: true` additionally, than `cellattr` will have `rawObject` as array at the first processing of input data and as object with named properties at the later processing. It makes the logic of `cellattr` more complex.

Because of that [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) introduced additional `rdata` parameter, which provides the data **allays** in object form. Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop since Tony have changed the licence agreement of jqGrid and have renamed his product to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) and [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)).

Below is the code fragment of the code

```
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.jgrid.cellattr = $.jgrid.cellattr || {};
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.cellattr, {
    customTitle: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        if (cm.name === "name") {
            return 'title="' + rdata.amount + ' (' + rdata.note + ')"';
        } else {
            return 'title="' + rdata.amount + ' (' + rdata.name + "; " + rdata.note + ')"';
        }
    }
});
```

See the corresponding demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/mme1krLj/1/