# jqGrid colModel not calling a function

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

In above code `attrSetting` is called. If I change it to `{"name":"A", "index":"0", "cellattr":attrSetting}`. It runs fine. So what should I do? The cellattr treats it as string not as a function.

```
var gridData = {"list":[{"A":"abc", "B":"def", "C":"IRIS", "D":"Testing","E":"17-12-                 2012","F":"Test", "attr":{"A":{"rowspan": 3}}},{"A":"abc", "B":"def", "C":"IRIS", "D":"Testing","E":"17-12-2012","F":"Test", "attr":{"A":{"display":"none"}}},{"A":"abc", "B":"def", "C":"IRIS", "D":"Testing","E":"17-12-2012","F":"Test", "attr":{"A":{"display":"none"}}}]};
$(document).ready(function(){
prepareGrid();
});
prepareGrid = function(colModel) {
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype    :   'local',
    contentType :   'application/json',
    data        :   gridData.list,
    loadtext    :   "Loading...",
    colNames    :   ['TB Element','GL Element', 'Company Name', 'Status', 'Date', 'User'],
    colModel    :   [
                     {"name":"A", "index":"0", "cellattr":"attrSetting" },
                     {name:"B", index:1 },
                     {name:"C", index:2},
                     {name:"D", index:3},
                     {name:"E", index:4},
                     {name:"F", index:5}
                    ],
    width       :   '500px',
    height      :   '200px',
    rownumWidth :   30,
    scrollrows  :   true,
    shrinkToFit :   false,
    rownumbers  :   true,
    viewrecords :   true,
});
};
function attrSetting(rowId, val, rawObject, cm) {
   var attr = rawObject.attr[cm.name], result;
   if (attr.rowspan) {
      result = ' rowspan=' + '"' + attr.rowspan + '"';
   } else if (attr.display) {
      result = ' style="display:' + attr.display + '"';
   }
   return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just change

```js
"cellattr":"attrSetting"
```

to

```js
"cellattr": attrSetting
```

Additionally you should be carefully in usage of jqGrid options. You current code contains many bugs. Just some example:

- If you use `datatype: "local"` you should **remove** `index` properties from `colModel` or use that values which are exact the same as the value of `name` property. If you don't follow the rule you will be unable to sort the grid columns and the searching/filtering of local data will not work too.
- You don't use `pager` or `toppager` options of jqGrid. In the case I strictly recommend you to specify `rowNum` option with some large enough value like `rowNum: 10000`. The defauls value of `rowNum` is 20 (see "Default" column in the table with [the options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)). So jqGrid will display just the first 20 rows from the array `gridData.list` which you specify.
- The values of `width` and `height` should be *numbers* like `500` or `200` instead of strings like `'500px'` and `'200px'`. The value of `height` can be the string `"auto"` or `"%100"`.
- There are no `contentType` option.
- I recommend you to use `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options.

Comment: Tanks for your suggestions. But my colModel comes from java which is dynamically made from database. There is no single function like `attrSetting`, I've 5 different functions. When I prepare the json for this call model, It takes string it self automatically. **I'm Making this json using jackson**

Comment: @Mitesh: You are welcome! Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5175127/315935) which describes a workaround which you can use.