# jqGrid column model creating at code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

I am creating column model at code behind, but I am stack at creating editoption for numeric values which is a function checks the value if its numeric otherwhise alert a message but I couldn't fit javascript function at code behind.

after I model at code behind I convert to json to use at in aspx page.

c# code behind

```
else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
{
    pr.name = prop.Name;
    pr.index = prop.Name;
    pr.sorttype = "number";
    pr.editoptions = new { dataInit = numericonly };
}
```

aspx

```
    function numericonly(elem) {
        $(elem).numeric(false, function() { alert("Integers only"); this.value = ""; this.focus(); });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is clear. JSON don't support functions as a type. What you easy can do is the following: 1) you fill **strings** as the value of `dataInit` on the server side. 2) you "pre-process" the column model and change illegal string values of `dataInit` to the reference to the corresponding function. You can "pre-process" the column model before creating of the grid or after creating inside of `beforeProcessing` callback or even later somewhere before starting of editing. Because `dataInit` will be used only during editing you have to fix `dataInit` at any time *before the editing will be started*.

To change `colModel` you can either use `setColProp` method or you can get *the reference* of internal `colModel` array by `var colModel = $("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");` and then do any required modification of some columns. The code will look about as below:

```js
function numericonly(elem) {
    ...
}

...
var colModel = $("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"), i, cm;

for (i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++) {
    cm = colModel[i];
    if (cm.editoptions != null && typeof cm.editoptions.dataInit === "string") {
        switch (cm.editoptions.dataInit) {
            case "numericonly":
                // function numericonly is visible here and can be used
                cm.editoptions.dataInit = numericonly;
                break;
            ....
            default:
                delete cm.editoptions.dataInit; // delete wrong value
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175127/315935) contains description of the same idea for the case of custom formatters.

Comment: @Mert: You are welcome! By the way I would recommend you to use `template` property of `colModel` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for details). You would have the same problem as with `dataInit` because the value of `template` property have to be object and not a string. Nevertheless  the usage of column templates mostly corresponds to format based of the **type of data** with all sorting, editing, searching and formatting settings. Using templates you can reduce `colModel` and make your code more readable and maintainable.